How to Create a Plasma TV-Like Gradient Border Effect Using CSS?"
Highligted Portion of netflix that I want the code for
Original Image of Netlfix with the curved radial gradient
I am trying to replicate a plasma TV-like glowing border effect similar to the one seen on the Netflix website. I believe the effect can be achieved using CSS gradient and layering techniques. My current approach involves using radial gradients and multiple backgrounds, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired look. But I am not able to create it.
What are the correct CSS techniques to:

Create a glowing, plasma-like border effect?
Properly layer gradients or pseudo-elements to enhance the effect?

I have uploaded two images of netflix, one the original image with the glowing plasma tv effect and the other with the annotated part that I am having problem replicating.
I am open to suggestions on:

Gradient properties (radial or linear)
Use of pseudo-elements (::before, ::after)
CSS filters or blend modes
Animations for a dynamic glow (optional)

Any guidance or code snippets to achieve this effect would be appreciated!
I am sharing the  HTML and CSS code for your reference:

Here is your HTML and CSS code converted into Markdown format:

HTML Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Netflix Plasma Effect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <nav>
            <span><img src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="Netflix Logo"></span>
            <div>
                <button>English</button>
                <button>Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="hero">
            <h1>Unlimited movies, TV shows and more</h1>
            <p>Starts at ₹149. Cancel at any time.</p>
            <p>Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.</p>
            <div>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                <button>Get Started</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="curved-container"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


CSS Code
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Martel+Sans:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800;900&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

/* General Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Main Container */
.main {
    position: relative;
    height: 70vh;
    background-image: url("https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/vlv3/729ce5c2-d831-436a-8c9d-f38fea0b99b3/web/IN-en-20241209-TRIFECTA-perspective_4aef76eb-7d5b-4be0-93c0-5f67320fd878_large.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.main .box {
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.69;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

/* Add Overlay for Plasma Effect */
.main::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(50% 100% at 50% -30%, rgba(64, 97, 231, 0.5) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    mix-blend-mode: screen; /* Blends the plasma overlay for glowing effect */
}

/* Navigation Bar */
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

nav img {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}

nav button {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

nav button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Curved Container */
.curved-container:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: -.25rem;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(33, 13, 22, 1) 16%, rgba(184, 40, 105, 1), rgba(229, 9, 20, 1), rgba(184, 40, 105, 1), rgba(33, 13, 22, 1) 84%);
}

/* Hero Section */
.hero {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    gap: 20px;
    height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.hero h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.hero p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.input-container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.input-container input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
}

.input-container button {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input-container button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}


Now I am sharing the output that I am getting when I execute the code given above
enter image description hereOutput Error in Netlfix Clone

I applied it to a full-screen div, but the gradient does not behave as expected, and I can't seem to achieve a glowing border that appears similar to the plasma TV effect.
I tried copying through inspect element but even then I couldn't perform it.
